# Age of Avram (Avraham) when he left for Kena'an out of the Ur Kasdim?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, age, parashat-noach, abraham, parashat-lech-lecha

[Nechemyah 9:7-8](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt35b09.htm#7) teaches that it was HaShem who brought (or called?) Avram forth out of the Ur Kasdim.

[Bereshit 11:31](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0111.htm#31) teaches that Terach took his whole household in which included Avram and they went forth from Ur Kasdim to go into Eretz Kena’an; and they came unto Charan (Haran), and dwelt there.

Later in [Bereshit 12](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.12.1-6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) we read that Avram had to leave this land of Charan, away from there which he came from, away from his father's household to the land HaShem will show him, which according to verse 5-6 is the land Kena'an.

I always thought the calling of Avram began at [Bereshit 12:1](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0112.htm#1) 'Lech Lecha', but after reading this verse could it be possible HaShem called Avraham's whole household (from Terach) at first?

And second if Avram left for Kena'an a second time at the age of 75 then how old was he when his father Terach took them out of the Ur Kasdim?

Comment: found this website with a lot of calculations (but still looking for some sollid answers) http://alhatorah.org/Duration_of_the_Egyptian_Exile/2#fn29

Comment: Abraham would have been around 30 if you do the math.

Comment: We don't need Nechemyah 9:7-8 to teach us that it was HaShem who brought (or called?) Avram forth out of the Ur Kasdim. HaShem said so Himself to Avram, in the _Berit bein ha-Betarim_ ([Bereshit 15:7](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0115.htm#7)).

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Ibn Ezra on Shemot 12:40](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.12.40?lang=en&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en), Avraham was 70 when he left Ur.

Comment: In [the body of] the question the OP asks: "... _**if Avram left for Kena'an a second time at the age of 75** then how old was he when his father Terach took them out of the Ur Kasdim_"? (Emphasis mine.) Does the Ibn Ezra contend Avram left Ur [Kasdim] twice? Was he 70 the _first time_ he left (when Terach took them out of the Ur Kasdim)?

Comment: @TamirEvan I understood the OP's "a second time" as referring to when he left Charan, the first time being when he left Ur.

Comment: I see your point. The question has now become (for me) a little more confusing. I'll have to mull this over a bit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We know he was in Charan before the age of 52 as the Gemara states in Avoda Zara 9a:

> אלא (בראשית יב, ה) מואת הנפש אשר עשו בחרן וגמירי דאברהם בההיא שעתא בר חמשין ותרתי הוה

> Rather, the two-thousand-year time period of the Torah is counted from the time when it is stated about Abraham and Sarah: “And the souls that they had gotten in Haran” (Genesis 12:5), which is interpreted by the Sages as referring to the men and women who were brought closer to the Torah by Abraham and Sarah. Therefore, it was at this point that the Torah began to spread throughout the world. And it is learned as a tradition that at that time Abraham was fifty-two years old.

Tosfos points out that he left Charan twice:

> וגמירי דאברהם אבינו בההיא שעתא בר חמשין ותרתי שנין הוה - ואע"ג דכתיב (בראשית י״ב:ד׳) ואברם בן חמש (שנים) ושבעים שנה בצאתו מחרן שתי יציאות הוו שהרי בברית בין הבתרים היה בן שבעים ואז היה בא"י ושוב חזר לחרן ועשה שם חמש שנים כדאיתא בסדר עולם ובפ"ק דשבת (דף י. ד"ה ושל) הארכתי היטב:

Answer (score -2):

The Bible calculates years by lunar cycles. According to the Biblical calendar, Abraham died at 87 (175 biblical years). Thus Abraham was 37 when he left for Israel.

Comment: In [the body of] the question the OP asks: "... _**if Avram left for Kena'an a second time at the age of 75** then how old was he when his father Terach took them out of the Ur Kasdim_"? (Emphasis mine.) Was Abraham 37 when Terach took them out of the Ur Kasdim? Was he 37 when he left for Kena'an a _second time_? If he was 37 when he left Ur Kasdim for Kena'an a _second time_, "_how old was he when his father Terach took them out of the Ur Kasdim_" the first time (to paraphrase the OP's actual question)?

Comment: Who's idea is it that the Bible calculates years by lunar cycles, and the ages stated need to be halved?

Comment: @TamirEvan Good question. As for the idea, see the last few paragraphs [here](https://blogs.timesofisrael.com/young-abraham-differed-from-what-we-think/).

Comment: (1) As you bring an article from a personal blog on a news site to support your idea of how the Bible calculates years, it would be safe to assume this is a novel idea. Therefore, it would be better to elaborate on it, or at least quote/cite your source(s) for it (and not just a 'here' labeled link), in the body of your answer.

Comment: TurkHill (2) The author of that linked article uses the 'lunar cycles as years' hypothesis (that you mention in your answer) to explain pre-flood life-spans (e.g. Adam's 930 years as being around 77 of our years). For explaining post-flood years (like Abraham's age when he left for Israel/Kena'an, stated in your answer), he uses a 'warm/cold season as a year' hypothesis, instead.

Comment: (3) Also, in that article, he says "_that Abraham was 37 years old when he left **Haran** with his wife and nephew and moved to Canaan_" (Emphasis mine). In your answer, you're ambiguous about the place he left from, but from Abraham's age that you quote, it is Haran. In the question, the OP asks at what age did he leave **Ur Kasdim** (the _first time_ he left for Kena'an), as he was 75 when he left **Charan** (the _second time_ he left for Kena'an). Based on that, you haven't answered either of the OP's questions, but only commented on [one of] his premise[s].

Comment: @TamirEvan Good points. I will try to rethink some of my answer. In any case, Abraham must not have been very old at all. Probably still around his mid-thirties, a young man.

Comment: How can lunar cycles halve the ages? A lunar year is approximately 11 **days** less that the solar year. The lunar cycle would be no more than 1100 days less than the solar years which could not have the count.  Also there are usages that show that the lunar and solar cycles must be reconciled such as the requirement that Pesach be in the spring (unlike Ramadan which rotates) an the usage of the angels saying that Yitzchak would be born at the next solar cycle (when the mark on the wall is next touched by the sun which is a solar year). Similarly the solar year was used for the flood of Noah.

Comment: @sabbahillel Turk Hill (or [the blog post he's relying on](https://blogs.timesofisrael.com/young-abraham-differed-from-what-we-think/)) means lunar month, which is used to bring down the pre-flood life-spans to something closer to our own (by dividing them by 12). As I mentioned in [a previous comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70449/age-of-avram-avraham-when-he-left-for-kenaan-out-of-the-ur-kasdim#comment404237_121813), That blog post uses a 'warm/cold season as a year' hypothesis (my labeling) to bring Abraham's life-span to something closer to our own (dividing it by 2).

Comment: I find it ridiculous to sometimes divide by 12 and other times divide by 2 just to make the ages *seem* more in line with what a person expects. As an example, it would be like dividing the age of Moshe Rabbeinu but not dividing any of the other years mentioned in Shmos. Similarly, one would have to arbitrarily change the way years were calculated in the middle of the lists in order to change the count from Shem through Terach. For example Serug was 30 years old when he fathered Nahor & lived 200 years after that. Seth son of Adam lived 105 years to sire Enos 105/12 = 8.75 which is ridiculous

Comment: Why is it ridiculous? Isn't saying a human lived for 200-900 years ridiculous? Saying that Abraham was 30 when he left makes sense since this is often the time young men start their own life. How do you know the Biblical prophets didn't calculate using the warm/cold season hypothesis? Lunar cycles have ages because that was how ancient humans calculated time.